# Does a python 3.7 install remove an existing python 3.5 install?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm considering upgrading to Python 3.7 from 3.5. Does anybody know if a Python 3.7 install from python.org will remove an existing Python 3.5 install? Thanks

Comment: Which operating system and package manager are you using? It depends.

Comment: OS is rather important... Anyway, if you upgrade, it kinda implies removing the previous version. If you just install 3.7, it is a new install and shouldn't touch the old one (other than perhaps changing which Python version is in path).

Comment: I'm on a Mac OSX High Sierra version 10.13.2 and I am using the macOS 64-bit installer from the https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/ page

Comment: No, but your path maybe changed so it doesn't see the Py3.5 install. Usually you will find the versions in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` (note: system versions are usually located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`)

Comment: I want to retain my existing Python 3.5 version. I want to ensure that code I wrote in 3.5 is compatible with 3.7 before removing 3.5.

Comment: Ensure you have both `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7` are in your path and explicitly call the version you need, e.g. `> python3.5 script.py` and `> python3.7 script.py`. If you just use `python3` it will only pick up the first one in your path.

Comment: Thanks much, I just checked my path and I see the 3.5 version. I'll check again after I install 3.7.

Comment: I just installed 3.7 and it did not remove 3.5. I also checked my path and both 3.5 and 3.7 are in the path.